# Angular / Typescript Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some code which is reading xml then parsing the data.

So here's the code:

```
data = [];

  ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getData().subscribe(XMLResult => {
    const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    parseString(XMLResult, function (err, result) {
       console.dir(result.listResponse.instance); // Returns Array
       this.data = result.listResponse.instance; // Here's the line giving me the error
    });

 });
}
```

Console.log is returning the data like this:

```
Array(10)
  0:
   $: {id: "23" name: "name 1"}
  1:
   $: {id: "45" name: "name 2"}
```

etc

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current approach, `this` does not refer to your component anymore.

Modify your callback to use an arrow function, so that you don't lose the scope:

```
parseString(XMLResult, (err, result) => {
  console.dir(result.listResponse.instance);
  this.data = result.listResponse.instance;
})
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value
>   (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the base object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an
>   object-oriented style of programming.